# where to store 100s of images in iPad photo app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, nsdocumentdirectory

i am working on a iPad photo app, where i have to download 100s of images from web and have to store in app locally so that i can access it even if there are no internet connection. So for now i have store it to App's document directory . Is it be ok to store 100s of images in App's Document directory or is there any other way to store it. Please have a reply on it.

Comment: It's definitely OK to store images in Document folder, I used to store  over 300 icons and thumbnails downloaded from webserver in my app

Comment: Hi Eric, but Apple says the files stored in Documents Directory will be synced to your iCloud. So all the images specific to only for app will be publicly available. How to block it by being synced to iCloud??

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store it in Document directory.

And also consider its size, if these are big files you can go for zip and save.

Comment: May be total size will be around 40-50 mb. How can we zip it? Does Apple accepts an app, with a big size data on App's document directory?

Comment: App doesn't check that kind of thing.  That is up to the user.  If they don't like your app using their space, they will uninstall it.  However, if it is something that can be redownloaded, you should use the cache folder instead.

Comment: 40-50mb is big, but not too big.  I have a few apps that are a gb or more, mainly large games such as Myst and Riven.

Comment: As you download them they are not part of the boundle. BTW, if you can store them in JPEG format then zipping does not make much of a sense. Before you invest in time for coding just zip some jpegs locally on your pc/mac and compare the sizes.

Comment: @ if it is png or jpeg, zipping does not make a large differnce may be of 1-5%, so it depends on user, what format he is taking.

Comment: Ok thank you guyz. I was just checking is there any better alternative way, like using CoreData. Can we store image to CoreData without storing it to documents directory?

Comment: Core data is a way to store, but it will lead to another level of complexity. As you need not to search filter sort etc with all those images,

Comment: Hey Guyz, i have read in other stackoverflow Q&A that storing images in Documents Directory will be synced to iCloud accounts, which is undesirable for my app. Those images are private images which shall not be downloadable i mean it can only be seen through my app. Any Solutions???

Comment: then surely go for coredata / sqlite.